# ImageMagick white out border stripes

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to white out borders of an image. That is, white out 100 px vertical stripe from left, and similarly from right, top, bottom. The following works for left:

```
mogrify -crop +100+0 -background white -gravity west -splice 100x aaa.tif
```

But I cannot figure out how to do the same with other sides. I tried many geometries, east, west, this, that, no success. Also please let me know if there is a better alternative than the above command.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a rose:

[image]

*I'll do the borders with yellow and magenta so you can see what I am doing on StackOverflow's white background.*

**All Sides**

Shave 10px off all sides and then put 10px back on all sides:

```
convert rose: -shave 10x10 -bordercolor magenta -border 10 result.png
```

[image]

**Right Side**

```
convert rose: -gravity east -chop 10x -background yellow -splice 10x result.png
```

[image]

**Left Side**

```
convert rose: -gravity west -chop 10x -background yellow -splice 10x result.png
```

[image]

**Top**

```
convert rose: -gravity north -chop x10 -background yellow -splice x10 result.png
```

[image]

**Bottom**

```
convert rose: -gravity south -chop x10 -background yellow -splice x10 result.png
```

[image]

**Left and Right**

```
convert rose: -shave 10x -bordercolor magenta -border 10x result.png
```

[image]

**Top and Bottom**

```
convert rose: -shave x10 -bordercolor magenta -border x10 result.png
```

[image]

Tags: ImageMagick, border, bordering, inside, gravity, one side, multiple sides, edges, framing, frame, overpaint, white-out

If you want the equivalent of Photoshop's "Border Outside" just omit the `-shave` or `-chop`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth exploring [`-extent`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#extent) option, but I feel it could be quicker just to append padding.

For example...*(using blue for visual example)*

```
convert -background blue \
        -size 100x xc:blue \
        \( rose: -crop +50+0 \) \
        -size 100x xc:blue \
        +append \
        output.png
```

[image: padding on both ends]

Comment: Ah! I misread the question. @MarkSetchell's answer would be an ideal solution.